# Kotlin inflate in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un problema, deseo mostrar un layout full screen para hacer algo similar al `progressBar` pero **fullscreen**.
Obtuve un ejemplo en github que lo ejecuté y anda

https://github.com/kmvignesh/FullScreenProgressBar

El problema es que al incorporarlo a mi proyecto no anda, no tira error ni nada pero no se renderiza el layout, es decir, nunca se infla el xml.

Estoy trabajando en un **fragment**, a diferencia del ejemplo:

```
var dialog = Dialog(activity!!,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar)
val view = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_screen_progress_bar,null)
dialog.setContentView(view)
dialog.setCancelable(false)
dialog.show()
Thread.sleep(2000)
...
```

Agrego info.

De esta forma coloco los fragments en una Activity paa usarlos como menú inferiores con logos, tipo TABS

```
val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        navView.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_dashboard).isVisible = SharedApp.prefs.conf_visible
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_notifications, R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Luego en HomeFragment dentro de una Asynctask en onPre y en onPost coloco el código mencionado en la consulta, tratando de inflar el XML desde el Fragment

```
 inner class CopiarTxts(context: Context) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        var resultado: Boolean = true
        var mContext: Context? = context
        var count: Int = 0
        var dialog = Dialog(activity!!,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar)

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            val view = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_screen_progress_bar,container)
            dialog.setContentView(view)
            dialog.setCancelable(false)
            dialog.show()
            super.onPreExecute()

            //progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            //activity?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            //    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
        }
```

Y luego en onPost

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            dialog.dismiss()
```

Comment: Este código donde se encuentra, en el fragment o en la Activity? eso puede ser el problema.

Comment: El ejemplo que funciona bien esta en el MainActivity, yo necesito implementarlo desde un fragment, por ello no me funciona, no se que debería cambiarle para poder inflar desde el fragment

Comment: en que parte de tu Fragment lo llamas, podrías agregar un poco de código relacionado a esto?@desarrollosTELLO

Comment: Hola @jorgesys luego te agrego código pero lo agrego en una asynctask en onPreEjecute intento levantar el dialog y en el onpostEjecute intento cerrarlo. También lo he probado en el onclick de un botón con un sleep (creo que se llama así, la sentencia que espera unos milisegundos antes de continuar) y luego lo cierro, pero tampoco funciona. Estaba pensando, no sé si tendrá algo que ver de ponerlo en la actividad en la cual hago la llamada a esos fragment.

Comment: Los fragment los utilizo para hacer un menú inferior, un navController, entonces tengo una actividad general y 3 fragment que son menús con íconos, dentro de uno de esos fragment es que deseo hacer como un progressBar pero full screen para que el usuario no pueda hacer otra cosa antes de que termine el asynctask. Prove de poner un progressbar simple y tampoco lo visualiza, creo que todo esto está relacionado a que es un fragmento dentro de una actividad.. pero he probado varias opciones que he leido como la que puse en la pregunta y no obtuve buenos resultados

Comment: En la lìnea de código en donde hace el inflate, también prove poniendole, luego de la vista, la palabra container, y como tercer parámetro el false, pero tampoco anda, con el true al final directamente me da error y se cierra la APP pero he leido que muchos opinan de ponerle el container, que sería como el elemento padre, es decir, la actividad pero tampoco me funciona